# LibreOffice 4.0 looks ugly in KDE

Tags: kde, libreoffice

I installed recent LibreOffice version (4.0) but it looks so ugly in my KDE on Linux Mint, as shown in the following picture... how can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: I took [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4?s=c82421e5-38e4-4a19-9788-235e02b86bb2#new-answer) installation instructions.

Comment: @m0nhawk I see what you did there ^^

Comment: http://ask.libreoffice.org/ might also be useful. But try selecting a "Persona" (option Personalization from your snapshot).

Comment: I know the answer to your question, if you post in the right place I can jump right on it.

Comment: @Souta Mint built from ubuntu so this is not correct askubuntu include kubuntu so this is the right place for my question.

Comment: @carnendil Thank you... unfortunately I tried Persona but it didn't fix this issue! This problem happens when GTK theme takes default values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then typing：
. Open the terminal，then typing the command line：

sudo mv /opt/libreoffice4.0/ure/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /opt/libreoffice4.0/ure/lib/libstdc++.so.6.old

and press enter.

. Open the libreoffice.

The answer from ： https://www.bdjl.de/localhost/?tag=kde

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question was supposed to be off-topic. But anyway will still answer.

There is a package that will provide LibreOffice integration with KDE.

Type `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-kde` and that's it!

Comment: This is not the right answer because libreoffice-kde is 3.6 version where version 4.0 is downloaded packages so they will not work